# cannot implement OnMapReadyCallback

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a project with Navigation Drawer, and one of the fragments should be with Google Map.

I'm trying to implement a OnMapReadyCallback interface but it doesn't resolve that symbol.

I have already tried to update Google Play services.
Here's my build.gradle :app

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv_v3"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'


}
```

And here I'm trying to implement this

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, onMapReadyCallback {

    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //set the fragment initially
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have conflicting Google play services packages...  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'`
And   `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'` and if you want maps, only use the maps dependency not all of the play services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo...  You have imported this.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
```

So this needs to be capitalized

```
onMapReadyCallback
```

Also, make sure you have the same version of play services if you are going to be using multiple of them (though you seem to only need maps)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent so much time on this mere trifle! Definitely gonna remember Java is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Add this in your dependency List

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
```

and re-sync and run

Comment: still the same, Error:(19, 69) error: cannot find symbol class onMapReadyCallback
Note: /Users/krzak/AndroidStudioProjects/CV_v3/app/src/main/java/com/zakrzewskibartlomiej/cv_v3/MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: @krzk can u remove compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0' line and re-sync once

Comment: same, Error:(19, 69) error: cannot find symbol class onMapReadyCallback
Note: /Users/krzak/AndroidStudioProjects/CV_v3/app/src/main/java/com/zakrzewskibartlomiej/cv_v3/MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: Can u add this "multiDexEnabled true" in your "defaultConfig" section of your gradle

Comment: Can u just post your whole build.gradle file once

Comment: I'm not sure why you thought multidex would fix the compile error `cannot find symbol class onMapReadyCallback`